# C++ compiling module dependency problem. Logic problem

Tags: dependencies

I have two dll modules. Module A and B. "A" call's function "B". And "B" calls function "A" to place result. "B" dependes from "A", "A" depends from "B". When i compiling (clean) project - i have a problem. (I have to remove module dependency - comment some lines - compiling "A" -then "B" then uncomment lines, add dependency and again compiling "A")

## module A:

callFuncmoduleB(params);

## module B callFuncmoduleB

//  Qt logic new Thread and Http requests using signal->slots. On finished Http request - parsing it callPARSEFuncmoduleB;

## module B callPARSEfuncmoduleB:

callSETRESULTFuncmoduleA(result).....

## module A:callSETRESULTFuncmoduleA

callsFuncModuleGUI and set results to GUI

Comment: Header files should solve that problem.

Comment: Hm... I including all header files in each projects. That is not problem compiling another if one of them already exists. The problem is how resolved compilation cyclic dependency for clean project.

Comment: Is the error reported by the compiler or by the linker?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you really should try as hard as possible to not produce circular dependencies. There are a lot of ways around, and which one is best for you depends on the exact nature of your depedencies.

- merge the two DLLs into one
- use a callback mechanism (function pointers, some interface defined in B) to pass the dependency at run time
  e.g. `callFunctionInB(args, callbackInA)`
  -

If you **MUST** have the circular dependencies, you will have to wade into the toolchain a bit deeper, starting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkt2hd12%28v=VS.90%29.aspx). In short, it is possible to create a stub `.LIB` file you need to link to a DLL without actually compiling the DLL.

Reference: [circular dependencies between dlls with visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362830/circular-dependencies-between-dlls-with-visual-studio)

Comment: Your answer is usefull. Thanks.